# Menu on Wordpress, changes by page

Tags: php, if-statement

What I'm looking to do is add a separate menu for each wordpress page on my site. I did some research and found that

```
<?php if (is_page('our-staff')): ?>

<?php wp_nav_menu('menu-side'); ?>

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if (is_page('contact-brian')): ?>

<?php wp_nav_menu('menu-home'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Is supposibly supposed to switch the menu from, menu-side while looking at the our-staff page, and it will change again when the page is contact-brian, it will change to the menu-home menu.

The problem is, I cannot get both menus to appear, its either one or the other

when you view our-staff page, i want the menu-side menu to appear, and nothing else. 
When you view the contact-brian page, i want only the menu-home to appear –

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `if` before the first `wp_nav_menu`? An `endif` with no preceding `if` is usually a bad sign.

Comment: You have it programmed, either 1 or the other.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want both to appear?

Comment: Okay when you view our-staff page, i want the menu-side menu to appear, and nothing else.

When you view the contact-brian page, i want only the menu-home to appear

Comment: I cannot seem to find anything that might conflict with the If functions